WARN Found screens with the same name nested inside one another. Check: Main, Main > Main, Main > Login, Main > Login > Login
import "./global.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AppStore, makeStore } from "./src/reduxStore/store";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/auth/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/screens/auth/RegisterScreen";
import MainScreen from "./src/screens/protected/MainScreen";
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: undefined;
  Register: undefined;
  Main: undefined;
};
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<any>();

const AuthScreensStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={ProtectedScreenStack} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProtectedScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Main"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
        name="Login"
        component={AuthScreensStack}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainApp = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("app loaded");
    const handleUserData = async () => {
      const userLoginFlag = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
      setIsLoggedIn(userLoginFlag === "true");
    };
    handleUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? <ProtectedScreenStack /> : <AuthScreensStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore | null>(null);
  if (storeRef.current === null) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <MainApp />
    </Provider>
  );
}


I'm currently working on a React Native project and have encountered a warning related to navigation that I'm seeking assistance with.
The warning I'm facing is: "Found screens with the same name nested inside one another." It seems to be related to how I've structured my navigation stack, specifically involving the nesting of screens.
I've been trying to resolve this issue by adjusting the structure of my navigation components, but I'm still receiving the warning. I suspect it might be due to the nesting of screens with the same name.
I've provided a simplified version of my code above.
Could you please review it and provide any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this warning? Or is there any better solution to achieve this. I'd greatly appreciate any assistance you can offer.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Try the below code I have made the changes in your code
import "./global.css";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AppStore, makeStore } from "./src/reduxStore/store";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import LoginScreen from "./src/screens/auth/LoginScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "./src/screens/auth/RegisterScreen";
import MainScreen from "./src/screens/protected/MainScreen";

export type RootStackParamList = {
  Login: undefined;
  Register: undefined;
  MainScreen: undefined; // Updated to reflect the new screen name
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<any>();

const AuthScreensStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Login"
      screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={ProtectedScreenStack} /> // Updated to use the new screen name
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const ProtectedScreenStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="MainScreen" // Renamed from "Main" to "MainScreen"
  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
>
      <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} /> // Renamed from "Main" to "MainScreen"
      <Stack.Screen
    options={{
      headerShown: false,
    }}
    name="LoginScreen" // Renamed from "Login" to "LoginScreen" to avoid conflict
    component={AuthScreensStack}
  />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const MainApp = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("app loaded");
    const handleUserData = async () => {
      const userLoginFlag = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");
      setIsLoggedIn(userLoginFlag === "true");
    };
    handleUserData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn? <ProtectedScreenStack /> : <AuthScreensStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore | null>(null);
  if (storeRef.current === null) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <MainApp />
    </Provider>
  );
}


Please explain how this wall-of-code actually addresses the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers.
